# For $ab+bc+ca=3$, when does $\prod_\text{cyc}(a^8+1)(a^4+1)=\prod_\text{cyc}(a^2+1)^2$?

Tags: inequality, products, symmetric-polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Suppose that $a,b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that
>   $$(a^8+1)(b^8+1)(c^8+1)(a^4+1)(b^4+1)(c^4+1) \geq (a^2+1)^2(b^2+1)^2(c^2+1)^2$$
>   When does equality hold?

I used Hölder and got equality at $ a = b = c = 1 $

The rest is analogous. I hope for a solution

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your proof?

Comment: @Tortugut I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg That's what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S
$$\prod_{cyc}((a^8+1)(a^4+1))\geq\prod_{cyc}(a^6+1)^2.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^6+1)\geq\prod_{cyc}(a^2+1)$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^4-a^2+1)\geq1.$$
Now, by AM-GM, C-S and since $$(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\geq\frac{8}{9}(ab+ac+bc)(a+b+c)$$ it's
$$\sum_{cyc}c(a-b)^2\geq0,$$ we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^4-a^2+1)\geq\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{64}\prod_{cyc}((a^2+1)(1+b^2))\geq\frac{1}{64}\prod_{cyc}(a+b)^2\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{64}\left(\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\right)^2=\frac{1}{9}(a+b+c)^2\geq\frac{1}{9}\cdot3(ab+ac+bc)=1.$$